で scope marker used for context of conversation?
I read this post a while ago:
Is this で with 思い当たる the particle or te-form
And considering it is the scope marker here, does it indicate the context for the statement/talking point that comes after?
''あっ あと天国って場所で何か思い当たることないですか？''
''Within the scope of a place/places called heaven, does anything come to mind?''
(When it comes to a place called heaven, does anything come to mind)
Xで言ったら
''Speaking within the scope of X
(Speaking within/about the context of X)
Is this a correct understanding of it? Are both of these considered scope?
